# svctraceviewer exe in Windows 2008 Enterprise Server

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008-r2, svctraceviewer

I have a WCF service running on a Windows 2008 Enterprise Server. I just enabled Tracing on in App.config  of the service. I have been trying to find the svctraceviewer.exe on the server and am not able to.

I tried to google and they say it will be in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.1\Bin\SvcTraceViewer.exe. But I don't have this folder in Windows 2008 server.
I see all versions of .Net Framework in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET

Appreciate your help in Advance.

Answer (score 23):

Directly download it here! Searching an hour for this, which isn't needed.

http://goo.gl/ZbrZS1

Comment: Saved installing some GB's, worth it!

Comment: Downloading an exe from a stranger and running it on your server is a very bad idea. Install the Windows SDK instead.

Comment: I fully understand your advice. Most people will just use it at a (developers) PC. Scan it with www.virustotal.com or compare it with the file of Microsoft. It's genuine. But would be nice if Microsoft hosted it.

Comment: @KoalaBear - its digitally signed by Microsoft Corporation, so should be trustworthy ;)

Comment: @Jimbo No. It is not trustworthy.

Answer (score 2):

On my machine (2008) its located here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\SvcTraceViewer.exe

Comment: Thanks for this! Why download when it's already on my machine? For me it was here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools

Comment: And how did it get there? Magic? Or maybe somebody just installed the SDK like the path indicates?

Answer (score 2):

It's included in the [Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11310)

Comment: Even if the link already is dead - this is the only valid answer.