# SvcTraceViewer Tool

Tags: wcf

Where can I get the SvcTraceViewer Tool please?

I tried downloading and installing many SDKs.

I've looked in the bins of the Program Files.

I need it to trace whats going wrong with my WCF call.

Answer (score 18):

You can get it by downloading the Windows SDK. The latest one can be found at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/, but if the link doesn't work, [searching for "Download Windows SDK"](https://www.bing.com/search?q=download%20windows%20sdk) should take you to the correct link.

When you install it, it may be added to the path variable. If not, you can search under the 'Microsoft SDKs' folder under 'Program Files (x86)'. For example, in my machine, it is found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools.

Comment: Unofficial download link can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19727399/951001

Also alternative tool here: https://github.com/martijns/SvclogViewer

Comment: all links are old and no longer works. :(

Comment: [Searching for "Download Windows SDK"](https://www.bing.com/search?q=download+windows+sdk) will show where it can be found. I've updated the answer with the new link.

Comment: @KoalaBear A copyright infringement (potentially with viruses) and an unknown open source tool that does not contain all features... Then rather download the whole SDK...

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Windows 10 and this works for me:
Use a search engine on "Win 7 SDK ISO", to get a Microsoft site result, such as this one:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8442
You may need to click into the site's 'Archives' section.
Then download the ISO, such as:
GRMSDK_EN_DVD.ISO
Right click the ISO file to Mount it to a local drive (such as your I drive), then double click this file to open it:
I:\Setup\WinSDKNetFx40Tools\cab1.cab
Scroll down to find this file in the cab:
FL_SvcTraceViewer_exe_x86_ln.3643236F_FC70_11D3_A536_0090278A1BB8
And right click to Extract it somewhere like your Documents folder.
Rename the file to SvcTraceViewer.exe and launch it.